# vba function returns closed recordset

Tags: vba, adodb

I'm calling a excel vba function with a recordset as return value. The function works alone, but the calling sub (searchSQL) gets closed object (error: object is closed). The debuger says recordcount=-1. Here the code:

The calling sub.

```
Public Sub SearchSQL(frm As IForm)
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String

    If (frm.dialogResult = vbOK) Then
        Sheets(1).Range("A2:E1000").Clear
        If (frm.searchBox = "*" Or frm.searchBox = "") Then
            query = "set nocount on;Select server_name from inventory.servers"
        Else
            query = "set nocount on;Select server_name from inventory.servers where server_Name like '" & frm.searchBox & "%';"
        End If

        Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset getSQLData(query) 'here error: the object is closed
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

The function:

```
Public Function getSQLData(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim c As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connectionstring As String

    connectionstring = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=Skynet-SQL\Skynet;integrated security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=false;initial catalog=SQL_Team_MGMT"

    Set c = New ADODB.Connection
    c.Open connectionstring
    Set rs = c.Execute(query)
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        Set getSQLData = rs
        Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs 'only test to show it works!
        rs.Close
    Else
        Set getSQLData = Null
    End If

    If CBool(c.State And adStateOpen) Then c.Close

    Set c = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

what's wrong with it?

Comment: In your getSQLData, you have a statement `rs.Close` that closes the recordset.

Comment: Btw: The line `Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset` is not needed. ` c.Execute` will create a new Recordset-object anyhow.

Comment: Thanks FunThomas.
1. I'm suprised, in the function getSQLData = rs -> I thought I could close rs because the function has now the recordset? It means I must relay on vba garbage collector closing the rs, connection etc.  in the function, since I'm leaving the function and those objects are still active?

Comment: The function has only a reference to the recordset, it's still the same object, not a copy. The GC is pretty reliable, so I think this is not an issue (it's even not needed to set the objects to Nothing). For the connection object: I would keep it open anyhow, not closing and opening it all the time. Use a global or static variable and check if the connection is already open